# Is it possible to create docker image from windows ISO?

Tags: windows, docker, driver, minifilter

I need a Windows docker image to run in a docker VM (backed by Hyper-V) to run tests on Windows mini-filter drivers there. I was able to run mcr.microsoft.com/windows:20H2-amd64 image but the mini-filter driver can not be started there because `fltmgr` driver is not started on the system for some reason.

So I'm wondering if I am able to create a custom Windows image original Windows ISO file and publish it to install in docker backed by Hyper-V or docker toolbox backed by VirtualBox

Comment: Docker is not a VM. Docker containers use the host's kernel and I would guess (I'm not a Windows Docker expert) that you need to install your driver on the host rather than in a container.

Comment: That's how it works on Linux (via kernel namespaces) on windows there is no such a feature so they are using lightweight virtual machines to run docker image, they do not share the kernel with the host